What is the exact meaning of 'your own app' in types of apps that are visible automatically in android?
From Android 11, package visibility is used to prototect user privacy.
Most app is not visible for my app according to:
https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility
Still some is automatically visible for my app:
https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/automatic#app-types-visible-automatically
But what is the exact meaning of 'your own app' in above link?
Same signature? Other components in this app?

IT says "your own app".  That means the app which is currently running.

Your own app refers to the app using which you query for information about the other apps. Without using an app you won't be able to query information about other apps.
